# asp.net 4.0 c# and sql performance issue

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

Thanks in advance.
I have around 1400 records to updated into my `sql server` database, every single day. for that 
i have created my web application using asp.net `c#` with sql server management studio. (i'm using `Dataset` in my application to insert these new records).

1. Each record will get stored in separate table
2. The 1400 records will in an excel format.
3. Before inserting each record in a table i have to fetch my older
   records (around 30 past records) to do some calculation.

when ever i upload this data to my sql it takes around 7 to 8 minutes. But once the first set of 1400 got updated, then if i try the next set of 1400 records, it takes around 2 to 3 minutes maximum. My problem is i have to update this records on daily basis. if i miss one day then only i will have more than one set of 1400 records. please help me with this
Thanks a lot

Comment: So what you actually ask ? how to improve it in speed ? or how to make it or what ?

Comment: *Each record will get stored in separate table* !

Comment: what is your problem? do you need the process to be automated?

Comment: Where is the performance issue?  Is 2-3 minutes too long?   Are you spending the most time in the database queries, database inserts or processing?

Comment: To improve the speed. when i open the sql connection for the first time it takes lot of time. how can i reduce this time

Comment: Hi RedFilter Every single record belongs to separate table... thanks